# Use of undeclared type 'XCTestCaseEntry'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi I can't seem to figure out why I am `Use of undeclared type 'XCTestCaseEntry'`

when using the following code in my .xctest:

```
import XCTest

#if !os(macOS)
public func allTests() -> [XCTestCaseEntry] {
    return [
        testCase(TrakkproTests.allTests),
    ]
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue while attempting to run unit tests for a custom framework I've built using the Swift Package Manager.

It turned out I had accidentally selected an iOS simulator in the Xcode scheme/device selector:

[image]

This compiled the code for iOS which satisfies the compilation condition of `!os(macOS)` and causes the error to occur. `XCTestCaseEntry` appears to be part of the [swift-corelibs-xctest](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest) project which provides XCTest functionality to non-Apple platforms (i.e. linux) but is not the same implementation Apple uses... I think.

The solution for me was to select "My Mac" in the scheme/device selector:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

looks like the typealias XCTestCaseEntry is added as part of the commit https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/commit/1c7fb283231ce53960a232aa7c771bb2d38dee62 on oct 2017.

I don't think the XCTestCase class  as part of the XCode/XCTest has this change yet. Where are you checking this anyway ?

Comment: `XCTestCaseEntry` can be found in both the `XCTestManifests.swift` and `LinuxMain.swift` files that are generated automatically by Xcode for your unit tests. They seem to be related to test-discovery on non-Apple platforms. See https://oleb.net/blog/2017/03/keeping-xctest-in-sync/